# How to hide a menu that scrolls to content after it's clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a nice menu in the Codepen below, yet it's not working like the way I want to.

```
var menu = document.querySelector('.nav__list');
var burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
var doc = $(document);
var l = $('.scrolly');
var panel = $('.panel');
var vh = $(window).height();

var openMenu = function() {
  burger.classList.toggle('burger--active');
  menu.classList.toggle('nav__list--active');
};

// reveal content of first panel by default
panel.eq(0).find('.panel__content').addClass('panel__content--active');

var scrollFx = function() {
  var ds = doc.scrollTop();
  var of = vh / 4;

  // if the panel is in the viewport, reveal the content, if not, hide it.
  for (var i = 0; i < panel.length; i++) {
    if (panel.eq(i).offset().top < ds+of) {
     panel
       .eq(i)
       .find('.panel__content')
       .addClass('panel__content--active');
    } else {
      panel
        .eq(i)
        .find('.panel__content')
        .removeClass('panel__content--active')
    }
  }
};

var scrolly = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var target = this.hash;
  var $target = $(target);

  $('html, body').stop().animate({
      'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
  }, 300, 'swing', function () {
      window.location.hash = target;
  });
}

var init = function() {
  burger.addEventListener('click', openMenu, false);
  window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollFx, false);
  window.addEventListener('load', scrollFx, false);
  $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',scrolly);
};

doc.on('ready', init);
```

**http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ygamdE**

What I want to do, is when I click on a menu item (so when I open the menu and I click one of the list items there), **I want to hide (get to the initial state) the menu automatically after the click.**

So when you click, it'll scroll to a certain ID, but the menu keeps being open. I want to close it. Is there any way to do this? I know we have a jQuery hide function, yet I can't get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a function called `openMenu()` that toggles whatever state the menu is in (will open it if it's closed, will close it if it's open). Just call that function inside of `scrolly()` after the browser animates the user to the position on the page. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VPmZYe

```js
var menu = document.querySelector('.nav__list');
var burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
var doc = $(document);
var l = $('.scrolly');
var panel = $('.panel');
var vh = $(window).height();

var openMenu = function() {
  burger.classList.toggle('burger--active');
  menu.classList.toggle('nav__list--active');
};

// reveal content of first panel by default
panel.eq(0).find('.panel__content').addClass('panel__content--active');

var scrollFx = function() {
  var ds = doc.scrollTop();
  var of = vh / 4;
  
  // if the panel is in the viewport, reveal the content, if not, hide it.
  for (var i = 0; i < panel.length; i++) {
    if (panel.eq(i).offset().top < ds+of) {
     panel
       .eq(i)
       .find('.panel__content')
       .addClass('panel__content--active');
    } else {
      panel
        .eq(i)
        .find('.panel__content')
        .removeClass('panel__content--active')
    }
  }
};

var scrolly = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var target = this.hash;
  var $target = $(target);

  $('html, body').stop().animate({
      'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
  }, 300, 'swing', function () {
      window.location.hash = target;
  });
  openMenu();
  
}

var init = function() {
  burger.addEventListener('click', openMenu, false);
  window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollFx, false);
  window.addEventListener('load', scrollFx, false);
  $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',scrolly);
};

doc.on('ready', init);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  line-height: 1.5;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.nav__list {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-flow: column wrap;
      flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 85vh;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -100%);
          transform: translate(0, -100%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}
.nav__list--active {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
          transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.nav__item {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
  position: relative;
}
.nav__link {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  background: #2b3033;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}
.nav__link:hover {
  background: #272b2e;
}
@media (max-width: 640px) {
  .nav {
    width: 70px;
  }
  .nav__list {
    height: 90vh;
  }
}

.burger {
  height: 15vh;
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #2b3033;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}
.burger:hover {
  background: #272b2e;
}
.burger__patty {
  position: relative;
  height: 2px;
  width: 40px;
  background: white;
}
.burger__patty:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
}
.burger__patty:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
}
.burger__patty, .burger__patty:before, .burger__patty:after {
  will-change: transform;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}
.burger--active .burger__patty {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
          transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.burger--active .burger__patty:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-7px, -7px) scaleX(0.7);
          transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-7px, -7px) scaleX(0.7);
}
.burger--active .burger__patty:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-7px, 7px) scaleX(0.7);
          transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-7px, 7px) scaleX(0.7);
}
@media (max-width: 640px) {
  .burger {
    height: 10vh;
  }
  .burger__patty {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
            transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  .burger--active .burger__patty {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8) rotate(90deg);
            transform: scale(0.8) rotate(90deg);
  }
}

.panel {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.panel__wrapper {
  padding: 7vh 7vw;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
          perspective: 1000px;
}
.panel__content {
  will-change: transform;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.7) rotateX(-230deg);
          transform: scale(0.7) rotateX(-230deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: center 80%;
          transform-origin: center 80%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}
.panel__content--active {
  -webkit-transform: none;
          transform: none;
  opacity: 1;
}
.panel__headline {
  font-weight: 700;
  opacity: 0.8;
  font-size: 48px;
  margin: 0 0 25px 0;
}
.panel p {
  margin: 0 0 25px 0;
  color: #1a1a1a;
  font-size: 24px;
  max-width: 800px;
}
.panel p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.panel__block {
  height: 3px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 0 0 25px 0;
}
@media (max-width: 640px) {
  .panel__headline {
    font-size: 36px;
  }
  .panel__wrapper {
    padding: 10vh 10vw;
  }
  .panel p {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

.c-blue {
  color: #5fc7ea;
}

.c-red {
  color: #e68568;
}

.c-green {
  color: #68e6ac;
}

.c-yellow {
  color: #e6d068;
}

.b-blue {
  background: #5fc7ea;
}

.b-red {
  background: #e68568;
}

.b-green {
  background: #68e6ac;
}

.b-yellow {
  background: #e6d068;
}

.logo {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 3vh;
  right: 3vw;
  z-index: 2;
}
.logo img {
  width: 65px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
          transform: rotate(0);
}
.logo img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) scale(1.1);
          transform: rotate(180deg) scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav">
  <div class="burger">
    <div class="burger__patty"></div>
  </div>

  <ul class="nav__list">
    <li class="nav__item">
      <a href="#1" class="nav__link c-blue"><i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav__item">
      <a href="#2" class="nav__link c-yellow scrolly"><i class="fa fa-bolt"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav__item">
      <a href="#3" class="nav__link c-red"><i class="fa fa-music"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav__item">
      <a href="#4" class="nav__link c-green"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<section class="panel b-blue" id="1">
  <article class="panel__wrapper">
    <div class="panel__content">
      <h1 class="panel__headline"><i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>&nbsp;Cameras</h1>
      <div class="panel__block"></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea molestias ducimus, eos asperiores, ab officia sint nostrum quia, corporis officiis id praesentium expedita numquam ad non error optio est in.</p>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
<section class="panel b-yellow" id="2">
  <article class="panel__wrapper">
    <div class="panel__content">
      <h1 class="panel__headline"><i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>&nbsp;Lightning</h1>
      <div class="panel__block"></div>
      <p>Paleo authentic mlkshk taxidermy, vinyl meditation lomo drinking vinegar sartorial raw denim Thundercats bitters selvage listicle. Keffiyeh Williamsburg gastropub McSweeney's.</p>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
<section class="panel b-red" id="3">
  <article class="panel__wrapper">
    <div class="panel__content">
      <h1 class="panel__headline"><i class="fa fa-music"></i>&nbsp;Music</h1>
      <div class="panel__block"></div>
      <p>Beard sriracha kitsch literally, taxidermy normcore aesthetic wayfarers salvia keffiyeh farm-to-table sartorial gluten-free mlkshk. Selvage normcore 3 wolf moon, umami Kickstarter artisan meggings cardigan drinking vinegar bicycle rights.</p>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
<section class="panel b-green" id="4">
  <article class="panel__wrapper">
    <div class="panel__content">
      <h1 class="panel__headline"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>&nbsp;Paper Planes</h1>
      <div class="panel__block"></div>
      <p>90's wayfarers lomo you probably haven't heard of them trust fund banh mi. Flannel Shoreditch dreamcatcher, quinoa flexitarian Banksy pickled post-ironic lo-fi. Photo booth asymmetrical tousled letterpress.</p>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
<a href="http://ettrics.com/code/vertical-layout-navigation/" class="logo" target="_blank">
 <img class="logo" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/45226/ettrics-logo.svg" alt="" /> 
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, when you click on one of the nav items you want to close the menu.

Inside your init function, add a listener to the menu. Call `openMenu()` which will toggle the nav_list.

```
var init = function() {
  menu.addEventListener('click', openMenu, false);
  burger.addEventListener('click', openMenu, false);
  window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollFx, false);
  window.addEventListener('load', scrollFx, false);
  $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',scrolly);
};
```